Need Drupal equivalent mysql Update query
I have plain mysql update query which needs to be append with existing values.
Example: appid coloumn containing 'abc' and now I want to append with some new values. Example: 'abc,xyz'
The below mysql query is working but I'm not sure how to do this in Drupal way mysql query. Could you please help on this?
Note: The main reason i'm looking for this kind of query, i don't want to use two query. One is to select the field and then second query to update. I need both in single query.
"update mytable set appid= "Concat(appid , ',' ,'xyz')" where id=1";

I tried the below query, seems not working.
$query = $connection->update('mytable');
$query->addExpression("CONCAT(appid, ',' ,'xyz')", 'appid');
$query->condition('id', 1);
$query->execute();


Docs reference for database queries https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/introduction-to-dynamic-queries

For an update query you need to use Update::expression() (there is no addExpression method):
$result = $connection->update('mytable')
  ->expression('appid', "CONCAT(appid, ',', :new_value)", [':new_value' => 'xyz'])
  ->condition('id', 1)
  ->execute();

A couple of other changes, the first one major:

If 'xyz' will come from a dynamic source, you absolutely have to use placeholders, to defend against SQL injection. Even if it's not dynamic, it's arguably better for readability to separate the value out from the SQL.
All the methods you're using are chain-able, so you might as well chain them.

